# Is it okay to store a casted reference (to my subclass of UIView) in my UIViewController?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Are there any dangers in storing a casted reference to `MyView` in my subclass of UIViewController? I am trying to avoid casting `self.view` every time I want to use an instance variable/method because it looks ugly. For example, let's avoid:

`[((MyView *)self.view) instancedView]`

`castedView` is defined at the same time as `self.view`

`castedView.instancedView` is a subview of `castedView` stored as an instance variable (a UIButton that I want to attach a tap event listener to, for example)

#### MyViewController.h

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
    @property MyView *castedView;
@end
```

#### MyViewController.m

```
@implementation MyViewController
    @synthesize castedView;

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      castedView = [[MyView alloc] init];
      self.view = castedView;
      // ... create gestureRecognizer named "onTap" that calls "whenTapped" ...
      [castedView.instancedView addGestureRecognizer:onTap];
    }

    - (IBAction)whenTapped {
        castedView.instancedView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
@end
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What you're asking is not clear. Is there a way you can rephrase it?

Comment: why do u even need to cast?

Comment: @Legolas I need to cast in order to access instance methods/variables of my subclass of UIView

Comment: You are not casting the view but creating a new instance of the view. If all you want to do is have another pointer to self.view that is cast as MyView* then remove the "alloc/init" line and set "self.castedVIew = (MyView*)self.view;". This is assuming your storyboard/xib is already creating the view as a MyView.

Comment: @BrianWalker I'm creating MyView programmatically. The way I'm doing it is the most efficient way when not using a storyboard.

Comment: @BrianWalker And you're right, it's not technically a cast

Comment: @primostyle Are you aware that **casting** means *converting* a pointer from one object type to another type?

Comment: @Merlevede Yeah sorry for the confusion. The only reason I called it casting was because this is the preferred alternative to *actually* casting it.

Comment: You can store the pointer to MyView in multiple locations. One will be in self.view and you can also store it in your castedView property. You should probably change your "castedView" references to "self.castedView" to access using the property. By default the ivar created by the synthesize will be "_castedView".

Comment: @BrianWalker If that's a problem, why does Xcode not complain? (Not trying to sound snobby)

Comment: I think it is because you have the "@synthesize castedView" which will create the ivar as "castedView". The @synthesize is not required anymore (the compiler will automatically add it as if you had "@synthesize castedView = _castedView".

Comment: There should be no problem doing this but I would make the property `weak` (or `assign` in pre-ARC) so you don't increase the retain count on your view

Comment: there's no for an ivar/property. setting the view in the initializer is enough. if you are just looking to make it convenient to access methods and properties of you custom UIView subclass you can simply add a method (or read-only property) that returns the view. casting it in view in this method will address compiler warnings.